# Dynamic Text view Adroid Game

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, game-development

I wanted to have a textview that will show the money of the player. But
`myMoneyTextView.setText(String.valueOf(acc.getMoney))`

doesn't update it I need to reopen the intent to see those changes. I want to change it when the player spend or gain money.

EDIT.

```
  private SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView;
private CustomButton up, down, menu, employ, sales, social, schedule, chart, states, mail;
private TextView comMon, comName;
private DataBase db;

Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_screen);
    officeRender();
    updateGame();
    butThread thread = new butThread();
    new Thread(thread).start();
```

comName = findViewById(R.id.companyname);
comMon = findViewById(R.id.money);

```
}
public void updateGame() {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            db = new DataBase(GameScreen.this);
            Account acc = db.getAcc();
            comName.setText(acc.getName() + " Ent.");
            
            String mon = String.valueOf(acc.getMoney());
            
            if (acc.getMoney() < 100000) {
                comMon.setText(mon);
            }
            else if (acc.getMoney() >= 100000) {
                comMon.setText(mon.substring(0, 3) + "k");
            }
            else if (acc.getMoney() >= 1000000) {
                comMon.setText(mon.substring(0, 3) + "m");
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: can you upload more code?

Comment: ive edited it bro i want the textview comMon to be dynamic like it changes every time the money send or if they gain

Comment: and where is your player code